# Odata results displaying user id values under certain columns instead of usernames when data imported into excel from devops?

Tags: azure-devops, odata, devops, azure-devops-rest-api, devops-services

[image: see image] I imported certain Workitems data from my Devops project into excel using Odata queries.
In that data under certain columns for eg: AssignedToUserSK its showing the user id values like this 06ea0e70-432d-4315-8ffd-87706966a7b6
Instead of this i need the username to be displayed instead of user id.
How to solve this?

Comment: Hi, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if you have any questions. If the answer could help, you may consider accepting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see usernames in the Odate query instead of user id, you need add the columns `AssignedTo.UserName`, `CreatedBy.UserName` and `ChangedBy.UserName`. Then you can see the user name.

Result:

[image]